# Residual plot looks like inverted change plot for prediction model

Tags: r, predictive-models, residuals, moving-average, filter

I have a very big problem with my predictive model. What i essentially do is that I predict the volume in a tank by studying the flow into and out of the tank. I use the two flows to construct a vector representing the net flow (flow in subtracted by the flow out).

First thing I do is to filter the values because they are very noisy. I do this with a moving average.

```
 >flow
-1.2030414 -0.9052991 -0.7513694 -0.9928622 -0.8817696 -1.1144226 -0.9364935 -0.8593083 -1.3240732 -1.0788943 -1.0750079 -1.2046967 -0.8266537 -0.8003841 -1.0144647 -1.0760028 -1.2727481 -1.1693427 -1.3255359 -1.1612553 -1.3089208 -1.1100377 -1.5040436 -1.0191814 -1.3319839 -1.1641094 -1.0651716 -1.0626996 -1.1470989 -1.3383050

> vol
1250.400 1248.664 1248.230 1249.098 1249.098 1249.532 1248.664 1246.928 1246.928 1247.362 1246.060 1244.758 1243.022 1242.154 1243.890 1243.456 1243.890 1243.890 1242.154 1242.154 1240.418 1238.248 1237.814 1236.946 1236.512 1237.380 1236.078 1233.908 1234.776 1236.078

f12 <- rep(1/12, 12)

smaFlow <- filter(flow, f12, sides=2)
smaVol <- filter(vol, f12, sides=2)
```

Then I use the data to predict the volume three minutes later by adding the current flow, next minute's flow and the minute after that's flow to the volume.

```
fl <- length(smaFlow)
compVol <- smaVol[1:(fl-2)] + smaFlow[1:(fl-2)] + smaFlow[2:(fl-1)] + smaFlow[3:fl]
```

Then I adjust the volume vector so that I don't compare two values that are minutes apart and calculate a residual. This is what the residual looks like when it's plotted.

[image: The residual of the prediction model]

It looks very weird, just look at the stuff happening around minute 8000. Then I looked at the plot of the flow and then I compared the residual plot and the flow plot. I discovered that the residual plot is almost an exact match when compared to the *inverted* flow plot.

[image: Red is flow black is residual]

What is going on?

**Edit:** This is what I've tried so far.

- Transforming the values by taking the natural logarithm of them
- Increased the prediction time. The values I've tried is three
  minutes, five minutes, 15 minutes and an hour.
- Increasing the moving average, in case this is all just noise.

Every time, the pattern comes back staring me in the face.

Comment: I think you are looking at a physical property of your system. Their might be time lags involved between inflow - volume - outflow and you don't take them into account. Also, I would not smooth the data and certainly not transform them. It would also be interesting to look at the geometry of the tank; in particular whether and how inflow and/or outflow depend on the volume.

Comment: It doesn't look like your model is suitable for the data you have.